# Create a executable for a scheme program with arguments

Tags: executable

I have a `scheme` program which is executed using the command
`; (primes<= n)` to give me all the primes less than `n`

For example, `; (primes<= 200)` gives me all the primes less than 200

How do I create an executable in Linux for the program below taking `n` as an argument

---------Scheme Program------------------------------------------------

```
    #lang racket

(define  (interval-list m n)
  (if (> m n)
      '()
      (cons m (interval-list (+ 1 m) n))))
(define (sieve l)
  (define (remove-multiples n l)
    (if (null? l)
         '()
         (if  (= (modulo (car l) n) 0)      ; division test
              (remove-multiples n (cdr l))
              (cons (car l)
                    (remove-multiples n (cdr l))))))
  (if (null? l)
      '()
      (cons (car l)
             (sieve (remove-multiples (car l) (cdr l))))))
(define (primes<= n)
  (sieve (interval-list 2 n)))
```

---

The above program is executed as (primes<= 100)prints all the primes less than 100

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll want to check your Scheme system's documentation for:

- compilation to native executable, and
- passing command line arguments from the OS shell

For example, if you were using [MIT/GNU Scheme](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/), I'd refer you to:

- [Compiling
  Programs](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Compiling-Programs.html#Compiling-Programs)
- [Custom command-line options](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Custom-Command_002dline-Options.html#Custom-Command_002dline-Options)

If you have flexibility over which Scheme interpreter you use, MIT/GNU Scheme is ported to many operating systems, including Linux, so would work well for the example above.

Answer (score 2):

In order to turn this Scheme program into a file that runs a Scheme interpreter, start it with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, and make it executable (`chmod +x /path/to/program`). A shebang line is the first line of an executable file and starts with `#!` followed by the full path to the interpreter. Since you're using Racket:

```
#!/usr/bin/racket
```

If you don't want to specify the full path to the interpreter, but want instead to have it looked up in the executable search path `$PATH`, then use

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
```

To access the command line arguments, Racket provides a command line parsing library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Command-Line_Parsing.html), or you can retrieve the command line parameters directly with [`(current-command-line-arguments)`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-command-line-arguments%29%29). You'll need to invoke `racket` with the `-f` option:

```
#!/usr/bin/racket -f
…
(define arg (string->number (vector-ref (current-command-line-arguments) 0)))
(display (primes<= arg))
(newline)
```

This cannot be combined with `#!/usr/bin/env` to look up `racket` in `$PATH`. If you want that, make your script a [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29):

```
#!/bin/sh
":"; exec racket -f "$0" "$@"
…
```

If you want your script to be portable across Scheme implementation, this is possible provided that the implementation follows [SRFI 22](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-22/srfi-22.html) (which Racket doesn't).

```
#!/usr/bin/env scheme-r5rs
…
(define (main argv)
  (display (primes<= (string->number (list-ref argv 1))))
  (newline))
```